# Capturing picture from webcam without flash?

Tags: webcam

I'm looking for a script to do this. I've found photobooth.js, but it seems to bug (when accepting the script to access to my webcam, all page is disapearing excepts the video...)

Do you know a script which do that job please?

Comment: I have the same issue with Photobooth and am looking for something still myself

Comment: Please keep me in touch if you find something...

Comment: I ended up using https://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/ it is 90% JavaScript and 10% Flash but it works everytime for me

Comment: Mmmh... I would like to avoid flash :-((

Comment: I wanted to avoid Flash as well but luckily this Flash is very small and has No UI...the Flash simply handles the Canvas creates and all the UI and control is done with JavaScript.  At least this library works much more reliably for me then all the JS only versions I tried

Answer (score 0):

I think, without flash it's problem, i'm using webcam plugin, here's a link: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/
It uses flash, but works fine for me.